# Is it possible to merge commits in git?

Tags: git, version-control, commit

Sometimes (it happens often) I make mistakes and making a kind of "fast fix" after push.

but for some commit clarity sometimes I'm making re fork (if that was in my fork) and make, commit all changes Again.

Is there someway to merge commits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, there's a way, and it is called *squashing*.

```
git rebase -i sha1_of_the_first_concerened_commit
```

Then replace all the *edit* of the commits below the concerned commit by *squash* (or *s*), save the file, and continue rebasing with `git rebase --continue`.

The next time you'll push, your push will probably be rejected, you'd need then to `git push -f`.

---

But in your specific case, there's no need to go trough this all, you can use `commit --amend` instead.

Let's say you commited, then made a quick fix on *file1*. You'd just need to add your file to the staging area:

```
git add file1
```

Then:

```
git ci --amend
```

And finally force push:

```
git push -f
```

Be careful when rewriting history, it is fine when you're the only one working on a repo, or you're sure no one pulled after you, otherwise it's a pain for the others.

Comment: I'm cleaning commit range fore clarity of pull requests )

Comment: Then squashing is *the* thing! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. What you want to look into is `rebase`. try

```
$ git help rebase # and read it
```

another option is `git commit --amend`. If the commit you are about to make should be merge with the current HEAD, you can *amend* it.

Both those options, rewrite history. So you will need to `git push -f` to send your changes upstream, if the affected commits are already on the remote end.

---

for an simpe example use case of **rebase**, suppose you have made 5 commits,

```
A--B--C--D--E
^ initial   ^ HEAD
```

and commit B is a quick fix to commit A,
and commit E is a quick fix to commit C.
So you want to merge B to A, and E to C.

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

you start with this:

```
pick A msg
pick B msg
pick C msg
pick D msg
pick E msg
```

you rearrange the commits so that the ones to be merge are below the ones to be merged into; that is B below A(already there) and E below C.

```
pick A msg
pick B msg
pick C msg
pick E msg
pick D msg
```

and you tell git, not to *pick* the commit, but to *squash* it; that is merge it to the above one - or *fixup* it - see the man page.

```
pick A msg
squash B msg
pick C msg
squah E msg
pick D msg
```

all done, save the file and git will rearrange and squash the commits.
so now you have:

```
A'--C'--D
```